# Lombok getters and setters being set privately

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I'm using lombok in intellij, and have the plugin installed.

My problem is that when I use the @Date notation in my class, only that class can see the methods created by lombok. So if my class declaration looks like this:

```
@Document
@Data
public class dbDocument {

@Id
private String uniqueId;
```

And the method

```
public String testGetter (dbDocument doc) {
    return doc.getUniqueId;
}
```

Will work inside the dbDocument class, but not in any other class. (where I get a Java: cannot find symbol error)

How can I fix/debug this?

Comment: I have no experience with lombok, so maybe someone else can provide better support than me, but it seems extremely dubious that an annotation could affect method/parameter visibility.  Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The annotation actually generates the methods. Will update if I get an MCVE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops.

Looks like I was spelling the method wrong while invoking it. Nothing to see here.